# How to convert Java code to Groovy code automatically

Tags: java, grails, plugins, groovy

I have written some code in Java and I need to convert the code to Groovy, to take advantage that Groovy offers. Is there any way to convert Java code to Groovy automatically or some existing plugins that can get me started in this direction?

Comment: "Most Java code is also syntactically valid Groovy." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groovy_%28programming_language%29 So strictly, there's nothing you HAVE to do. What you should change depends entirely upon what features of Groovy you need.

Comment: Converting the code automatically without fully understanding the resulting code is dangerous.  I'd rather put the existing code in `/src/java` (we are talking grails, right?) and rewrite from scratch, where it matters. Like @blagae said, there is no _need_ to rewrite it to use it.

Comment: Not true - `int[] ints = { 1,2,3 };` is valid Java but not Groovy. Groovy also doesn't have a `do`/`while` loop, although it's easy to emulate. There are a few more - see http://groovy.codehaus.org/Differences+from+Java

Answer (score 7):

Fun fact - Groovy has a tool for this already, called `java2groovy` - you can see it in the `bin` directory of your Groovy installation. It's a wrapper script that calls a class in the distro - `org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.java.Java2GroovyMain`.

Pay no attention to the warnings added to the header of the converted code:

```
!! NOT FIT FOR ANY PURPOSE !!
```

and

```
'java2groovy' cannot be used to convert one working program into another
```

On a more serious note - I'm pretty sure that code hasn't been updated in a long time, and that it wasn't very feature-rich at its peak.

My suggestion is similar to what the others have said - leave it as is if it's working and tested. If you do really need it to be in Groovy, there are a few problematic differences between Groovy and Java, primarily due to Groovy using the { } chars for a closure; Java constructs that use those (e.g. arrays) need to be converted. Also, strangely - there's no `do`/`while` loop in Groovy. And there are cases where runtime behavior is different from compile time, but Java uses what was compiled. Dynamic dispatch typically results better choices because Groovy looks at what the types *are*, not what it appeared they looked at compile time. But better is a problem if you're expecting it to be the same.

See http://groovy.codehaus.org/Differences+from+Java for a description of the problems and some workarounds.

Answer (score 6):

I would like to show it with an example program:

```
private static List<List> subn(int n, List li) {
    List<List> ret = new ArrayList<List>();
    if (n == 0) {
        ret.add(new ArrayList());
        return ret;
    }
    if (li.isEmpty()) {
        return ret;
    }
    T x = li.get(0);
    List xs = li.subList(1, li.size());
    for (List sub : subn(n-1, xs)) {
        sub.add(0, x);
        ret.add(sub);
    }
    ret.addAll(subn(n, xs));
    return ret;
}
```

For the first step I would like to remove static typing, though i am not agaist it but for such a small code, i would go for it.

```groovy
def subn(n, li) {
    def ret = new ArrayList();
    if (n == 0) {
        ret.add(new ArrayList());
        return ret;
    }
    if (li.isEmpty()) {
        return ret;
    }
    def x = li.get(0);
    def xs = li.subList(1, li.size());
    for (sub in subn(n-1, xs)) {
        sub.add(0, x);
        ret.add(sub);
    }
    ret.addAll(subn(n, xs));
    return ret;
}
```

This will change the character count:) but not the structure.
let us now change the array literals:

```groovy
def subn(n, li) {
    def ret = [];
    if (n == 0) {
        ret.add([]);
        return ret;
    }
    if (li.isEmpty()) {
        return ret;
    }
    def x = li.get(0);
    def xs = li.subList(1, li.size());
    for (sub in subn(n-1, xs)) {
        sub.add(0, x);
        ret.add(sub);
    }
    ret.addAll(subn(n, xs));
    return ret;
}
```

We see more chars trimmed, now lets change the if statement.

```groovy
def subn(n, li) {
    if (n == 0) return [[]];
    if (li.isEmpty()) return [];

    def ret = [];
    def x = li.get(0);
    def xs = li.subList(1, li.size());
    for (sub in subn(n-1, xs)) {
        sub.add(0, x);
        ret.add(sub);
    }
    ret.addAll(subn(n, xs));
    return ret;
}
```

I’m not really a fan of short variable names so next step is to rename some variables. In addition to this I’ll change the loop slightly to use the each function. The ‘it’ magic variable replaces the ‘sub’ variable.

```groovy
def subn(n, list) {
    if (n == 0) return [[]];
    if (list.isEmpty()) return [];

    def ret = [];
    def head = list.get(0);
    def remainder = list.subList(1, list.size());

    subn(n-1, remainder).each {
        it.add(0, head);
        ret.add(it);
    }
    ret.addAll(subn(n, remainder));
    return ret;
}
```

By adding the collections together we can simplify the loop a bit more:

```groovy
def subn(n, list) {
    if (n == 0) return [[]];
    if (list.isEmpty()) return [];

    def ret = [];
    def head = list.get(0);
    def remainder = list.subList(1, list.size());

    subn(n-1, remainder).each {
        ret.add([head] + it);
    }
    ret.addAll(subn(n, remainder));
    return ret;
}
```

Looking at the code it becomes clear that the ‘ret’ variable is just accumulating the results. We can use the collect method for this purpose instead.

```groovy
def subn(n, list) {
    if (n == 0) return [[]];
    if (list.isEmpty()) return [];

    def head = list.get(0);
    def remainder = list.subList(1, list.size());

    def ret = subn(n-1, remainder).collect { [head] + it }
    ret.addAll(subn(n, remainder));
    return ret;
}
```

In fact we really don’t need ‘ret’ at all if instead we just add the two collections together:

```groovy
def subn(n, list) {
    if (n == 0) return [[]];
    if (list.isEmpty()) return [];

    def head = list.get(0);
    def remainder = list.subList(1, list.size());

    return subn(n-1, remainder).collect { [head] + it } + subn(n, remainder);
}
```

Finally lets inline the head variable. It’s only used in one place anyway so not really worth keeping it. In addition we’ll use Groovy list indexing to remove the get() call.

```groovy
def subn(n, list) {
    if (n == 0) return [[]];
    if (list.isEmpty()) return [];

    def remainder = list.subList(1, list.size());
    return subn(n-1, remainder).collect { [list[ 0 ]] + it } + subn(n, remainder);
}
```

Comment: what's the deal with all those semicolons ;)

Comment: ... and the last `return` can be removed. Also, the first if, can be replaced as: `if (!n) return [[]];

Comment: and `isEmpty()` can be replaced by `empty`

Answer (score 2):

I recommend This ! Its worth Reading .
And it worked for me ! Kind of simple.

[Java To Groovy](https://web.archive.org/web/20150522053813/http://groovy.dzone.com/news/java-groovy-few-easy-steps)

Comment: While this may answer the question, please post relevant content into answer.  That way answer will be useful even when link is not working. (Currently this is a link only answer)